# Sequence of componentWillMount calls in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, reactjs, single-page-application

According to this page http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/ The render method for a component is called right in between the `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` methods amongst other places.

But the react.js documentation for component lifecycles here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html says that the `componentDidMount` methods of all child activities are called before the parent.  I can understand that `componentDidMount` is ok to call after any child components are rendered but how does the runtime know which children to call the `componentWillMount` function on before they are rendered?  Or am I right in assuming that `componentWillMount` is called for the parent activity first and then for the children (unlike `componentDidMount`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK. so here goes. If you have a simple structure with a parent and 2 children like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
</Parent>
```

Then the sequence of events firing will be:

1. `<Parent> componentWillMount()`
2. `<Parent> render()`, which starts to render children
3. `<Child> componentWillMount()` of the first child
4. `<Child> render()` of the first child
5. `<Child> componentWillMount()` of the second child
6. `<Child> render()` of the second child
7. `<Child> componentDidMount()` of the first child (these will start only after the last render in the tree has run)
8. `<Child> componentDidMount()` of the second child
9. `<Parent> componentDidMount()` (this one will run only after its last child has run `componentDidMount`)

You can find a [codepen example here](https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/XdOOjR?editors=0011).

Comment: @winvelt Any thoughts on why all the `componentDidMount()` start after the last render? I had been wondering about it lately but couldn't get any idea.

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be that it makes sense do mounting “bottom-up”, so children first. It ensures that the whole tree (with all children) is ready before it is mounted, and potentially prevents ugly build up of trees and children on screen (not sure this would happen).

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. I am wondering about is, why not the order is 3 → 4 → 7. I was expecting 3 → 4 → 7 and then 5 → 6 → 8. Why both components Did mount are together?