# reactJS componentWillMount is run after render method

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

in my reactjs app I do this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        myTasks: tasksData,
        processes: []
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/dashboard/processes')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function (json) {
        this.setState({processes: json});
    }.bind(this)).catch(function (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    });
}
```

Problem is that the render method is run bevor this and the json data isn't there right bevor the table is rendered

```
<BootstrapTable
      react- data={this.state.processes}
      search={true}
     options={options}
       striped hover condense
       pagination={true}>
       <TableHeaderColumn width='200' dataField='process' searchable={true} isKey><T value="dashboard.processes.process"/></TableHeaderColumn>
         <TableHeaderColumn width='100' dataField='status'><T value="dashboard.processes.status"/></TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn width='100' dataField='progress' dataFormat={progressBarFormatter}><T value="dashboard.processes.progress"/></TableHeaderColumn>
           <TableHeaderColumn width='100' dataField='deadline'><T value="dashboard.processes.deadline"/></TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
```

SO i got this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined
    at TableBody.eval (eval at ./node_modules/react-bootstrap-table/lib/TableBody.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:3702:1), :199:32)
    at Array.map (native)
    at TableBody.eval (eval at ./node_modules/react-bootstrap-table/lib/TableBody.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:3702:1), :198:47)
    at Array.map (native)
    at TableBody.render (eval at ./node_modules/react-bootstrap-table/lib/TableBody.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:3702:1), :197:39)
    at TableBody.render (eval at ./node_modules/react-proxy/modules/createPrototypeProxy.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:5252:1), :46:30)
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:4238:1), :798:21)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:4238:1), :77:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:4238:1), :797:25)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:4238:1), :824:32)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for me is to do this:

```
    if(this.state.processes.length === 0) return <p>Bitte warten sie ...</p>;
    return (
```

Answer (score 1):

Render is called after component will mount (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37123901/5813839). The problem here is a race condition. You fetch the json and asynchronously wait for the response, meanwhile render is called and breaks.

The fix is to allow your component to run without the json data present (blank or temporary holding values) and then as soon as the json is loaded into your state react will execute render again and update your component.

Comment: Sure, but you will have to update your post to explain what ```dashboard.processes.process``` is, it is unclear what dashboard is referencing. These should likely be referencing your state instead of some variable that is unset until your state is updated.

Comment: the one you mean is just a translating part that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data in a parent container component. If the container doesn't have data, render a loading element. When the data arrives, update the container components state with the data to render the child component with data. It's always a good idea to separate your concerns between container components for data fetching and state control, and presentational components to handle the visual aspects of the application. Take a look at [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) by Dan Abramov.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            processes: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/dashboard/processes')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json()
            }).then(function (json) {
                this.setState({processes: json});
            }.bind(this)).catch(function (ex) {
                console.log(ex)
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.processes ?
                <div class="loading">Loading data...</div> :
                <BootstrapTable
                  react-data={this.state.processes}
                  search={true}
                  options={options}
                  striped hover condense
                  pagination={true} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work, absolut no change ... only loading data... is printed ... Probably some synthax problems in your version?

Comment: there was no closing / tag on the BootstrapTable component in the render method. Try it now.

Comment: I just copied this `this.state.processes ?
                <div class="loading">Loading data...</div> : `

Comment: any further infos?

Comment: @Felix: Looks like there was a space in `<BootstrapTable react -data ... />`. Do you have that space in yours?